# Regex to get 00 if the string has less digits

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column that is giving me output like 'ABC2001' , 'ABC100145', 'ABC009282' ,' ABC1901'

I want to change this column value to have '00' in between literals and numbers if number is less than 6 digits. Something like -

```
COL_A
------------
ABC2001
ABC100145
ABC009282
ABC1901
```

Expected output

```
COL_B
------------
ABC002001
ABC100145
ABC009282
ABC001901
```

How to use regex for this ? Currently I am using

```
SELECT SUBSTR(COL_A,1,3)||LPAD(REGEXP_REPLACE(COL_A,'\D+'),6,'0') FROM TAB
```

and it is giving me output like -

```
ABC210073
ABC210073
```

Comment: What is wrong with the query you have right now? Why do you need a different solution?

Comment: I mentioned the output I am getting with my current query

Comment: The output you posted doesn't correspond to any of your inputs. In the output you show (why the same value twice, anyway?) the "number" part is already six digits, so you don't actually need to add any 00. So, again - what is wrong with your current query, or with what you say is your current output? I see nothing wrong with either one. Your query on the expected input (`COL_A`) produces exactly your desired output (`COL_B`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need (slow) regular expressions and can use simple string functions:

```sql
SELECT col_a,
       SUBSTR(col_a, 1, 3) || LPAD(SUBSTR(col_a, 4), 6, '0') AS col_b
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (col_a) AS
SELECT 'ABC2001'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC100145' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC009282' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC1901'   FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | COL_A | COL_B |
> | --- | --- |
> | ABC2001 | ABC002001 |
> | ABC100145 | ABC100145 |
> | ABC009282 | ABC009282 |
> | ABC1901 | ABC001901 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=c7f8c04a28cbeb9473eb45081b3cf91a)*

Comment: @mto - This worked !

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, for different prefixes:

1. usual string functions: trim/lpad/substr:

```sql
with table_name (col_a) AS (
SELECT 'ABC2001'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC100145' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC009282' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC1901'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
-- other different prefixes:
select 'ABC2001'     from dual union all
select 'AB100145'    from dual union all
select 'A-BC9282'    from dual union all
select 'A8C2374'     from dual union all
select '7x-ABC32129' from dual union all
select '123ABC8942'  from dual
)
select v.*, prefix||num as col_b
from (
    select
      col_a,
      rtrim(col_a,'0123456789') as prefix,
      lpad(substr(col_a,1+length(rtrim(col_a,'0123456789'))),6,'0') as num
    from table_name
) v
;
```

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=efd01caf2a511d547d68aaf8b0c86496)

2. using regex functions:

```sql
with table_name (col_a) AS (
SELECT 'ABC2001'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC100145' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC009282' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC1901'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
-- other different prefixes:
select 'ABC2001'     from dual union all
select 'AB100145'    from dual union all
select 'A-BC9282'    from dual union all
select 'A8C2374'     from dual union all
select '7x-ABC32129' from dual union all
select '123ABC8942'  from dual
)
select 
    col_a,
    regexp_replace(
       regexp_replace(col_a,'(\d+)$','00000\1')
      ,'0*(\d{6})$'
      ,'\1'
    ) as col_b
from table_name
;
```

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=04c8a6245c8cf83d3136be42ad3df320)

3. regex solution for padding numbers to the maximum their length, ie not knowing max numbers length(if it's not hard-coded 6):

```
select 
    v.*,
    regexp_replace(
       regexp_replace(col_a,'(\d+)$',rpad('0',max_num_length,'0')||'\1')
      ,'0*(\d{'||max_num_length||'})$'
      ,'\1'
    ) as col_b
from (
    select t.*, max(length(regexp_substr(col_a,'\d+$')))over() as max_num_length
    from table_name t
) v
;
```

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f344167a98d215a7b51212e2d4572133)